# ImageField not failing at IOError exception

Tags: python, django, ioerror, imagefield

Hay, i have a model which saves 2 images

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=make_filename)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to=make_thumb_filename)
    car = models.ForeignKey('Car')
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def save(self):
        super(Picture, self).save()
        size = 200, 200
        filename = str(self.thumbnail.path)
        image = Image.open(filename)
        image.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
        image.save(filename)
```

As you can see i have overwrote the save() method
I'n my view i have a simple try, except block, which checks for IOErrors (which are raised if a file other than an image is uploaded)

```
def upload(request):
    car = Car.objects.get(pk=1)
    try:
        picture = Picture(picture=request.FILES['image'], thumbnail=request.FILES['image'], car=car)
        picture.save()
    except IOError:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/test/")
```

However, the exception is raised, but the files are still written to the server (and db)

Any ideas how to make sure files dont get written if the IOError is raised?

**EDIT**

Fixed by writing a custom method

```
def is_accectable_file(filename):
    extension = filename.split('.')[-1]
    acceptable_filetypes = ['jpeg','jpeg','gif','png']
    if extension in acceptable_filetypes:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Then exiting my model to

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=make_filename)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to=make_thumb_filename)
    car = models.ForeignKey('Car')
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if is_accectable_file(self.picture.name):
            super(Picture, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
            size = 200, 200
            filename = str(self.thumbnail.path)
            image = Image.open(filename)
            image.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
            image.save(filename)
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

and my view to

```
def upload(request):
    car = Car.objects.get(pk=1)
    try:
        picture = Picture(picture=request.FILES['image'], thumbnail=request.FILES['image'], car=car)
        if picture.save():
            return HttpResponse("fine")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("invalid type")
    except:
        return HttpResponse("no file")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that (I assume) throws the IOError is being run *after* you call the `super(Picture,self).save()` method. Because of this, the picture getting written to the database even if the exception is thrown.

You just need to move the `super` call to after the setup code.

As an aside, if you're overriding `save` I'd recommend doing it as follows:

```
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
    ...
    super(Picture, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Otherwise you'll get an exception in any case where Django is passing in arguments to `save` (and I believe there are a few cases where it does, at least in the admin).

Comment: Thanks for this. I've amended my code and added the super call AFTER it does all the image processing, however nothing gets uploaded, and no exception is called.

Comment: If it were me, the next thing I'd do is add a print statement between each line so you can be sure it's doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: Can i do print's within a model?

Comment: As long as you're running devserver, yup! (Take them out before deploying to prod).

Comment: Right got it working thanks to a custom method (see original question)

Comment: Not to nitpick but you really probably want to use a Form for the validation -- there's nothing wrong with how you did it, but the "silent fail" of the save() method may cause you grief later. Better to validate with a form and have the save method throw something if wrong. Anyway, good luck!